# React why focus cannot be captured, but click can;

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Why should the focus event of input be executed before document. body. addEventListener ('focus', (e)=>{console. log ('here ')}, capture: true}

But click is later than document. body. addEventListener ('click ', (e)=>{console. log ('here')}, capture: true}

example：

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ReactTest extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener(
            'focus',
            (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('capture-focus');
            },
            { capture: true },
        );
        document.body.addEventListener(
            'click',
            (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('capture-click');
            },
            { capture: true },
        );
    }

    inputFocus = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('input-focus');
    };

    divClick = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('div-click');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <input style={{ border: '1px solid #000' }} type="number" onFocus={this.inputFocus} />
                <div onClick={this.divClick} style={{ border: '1px solid #000', width: '200px', height: '100px' }}>
                    点击
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

In Reactjs, I want to capture the click and focus of the page through the body to intercept them and complete some logic. Click can intercept, but focus cannot

In HTML, it can be intercepted. The following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input onfocus="foucs()" />
    <div onclick="click()">button</div>
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = (() => {
        document.body.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('capture-foucs');
        }, true);

        document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('capture-click');
        }, true);
    })
    function foucs(e) {
        console.log('start-foucs');
    }

    function click(e) {
        console.log('start-click');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I don't know why this is，who can help me